# Voltage divider equation giving wrong thermistor resistance

Tags: voltage-divider, temperature, thermistor

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBGQax.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm using the voltage divider equation to solve for thermistor resistance. I have:

```
V_source = 4.9v
V_therm = 2.95v
R_known = 9kohm
```

I rearrange the equation so that it looks like:

`R_therm =  ((R_known * V_therm) / (V_source - V_therm));`

And this results in a resistance value of approximately 13.6kohm, however, when I take the thermistor out of the circuit and measure its resistance directly (being sure not to touch it), the resistance measures ~11kohm. This 11kohm value makes more sense because it translates into an accurate temperature reading in Kelvins using the Steinhart-Hart equation. So, what am I doing wrong here?

edit: I know I'm converting the raw 10-bit ADC value to the `V_therm` value properly, because it's exactly the same value that my multimeter shows.

Basically it seems like I need to let the Arduino run for a bit, heat the thermistor, cool it, then after a while it starts giving proper resistance readings. Is there a reason it doesn't work properly from the get-go and/or anything I can do about it? I'm using a TTC-103 10k thermistor.

Comment: Schematic would help

Comment: What is the input impedance of your voltage measuring circuit?

Comment: Arsenal beat me to it. Your maths is correct IF you assume there is no current flow into the device measuring Vtherm

Comment: I'm not sure what the input impedance is, I'm using an Arduino Uno connected to my laptop that is getting 4.9v. This: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67171/input-impedance-of-arduino-uno-analog-pins looks like it says its < 10kohm? Also the resistance just suddenly changed to the correct (measured) value after running it for a bit and re-uploading the exact same code to the board a couple times. Any idea why this change could have occurred (so I can prevent it in the future)?

Comment: I would expect the resistance to go *down* due to self-heating, so maybe something else is wrong (like a flaky thermistor).

Comment: Yep thats what I expected too. It seems to work after I let it run for a while though.

Comment: Schematic, @Jake, schematic. Hit the button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: updated with a schematic, just using a simple voltage divider

Comment: Have you verified the thermistor voltage with a voltmeter, and not just your A/D?  That would be my step 1.

Comment: Yep, the thermistor voltage is consistently within 0.1V of the voltage measured by my multimeter. The step that that goes from the voltage to the resistance is what is kind of wonky.

Comment: That 0.1V makes a big difference here

Comment: sorry I meant 0.01 difference (off and on), I'm using 4.90 in my calculation and my voltmeter reads 4.90,4.91,4.92 back and forth